# Writing multiple strings to file in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am looking to write multiple strings to file for storage using android. Is it possible to add all strings to a toString using .getText and if so how. I am looking to create some edit text fields and take the information contained in these fields and write them to a file before then reading the file in a different activity. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far if it is any help:

```
package app.project.newapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    }

    public void saveClick(String filename, EditText v){

        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namet);
        EditText tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emerg_tel);
        EditText cond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conditions);
        EditText other = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.other);

        String userDetails = "Hello_File";
        String string = "";

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(userDetails, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            string=name.getText().toString();
            string=tel.getText().toString();
            string=cond.getText().toString();
            string=other.getText().toString();
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            try {
                BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        openFileInput("hello_file")));
                String inputString;
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
                }

                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your saveClick method, in the second try:

```
try {
    string=name.getText().toString() + "\n"
        + tel.getText().toString() + "\n"
        + cond.getText().toString() + "\n"
        + other.getText().toString();
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```